# How can I make my site fixed width in Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

How I can make my site fixed width to say 1920px? I don't want the layout to change as the browser is resized. I want to disable all the media queries and breakpoint based css. Scrollbars should appear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using the following css and html:

```
.fixed-width {
  width: 1920px;
  min-width: 1920px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

<body class="fixed-width">
  ...
</body>
```